# Switch power of PN532 on and off from ESP32?

Tags: esp32

I have a strange issue with PN532, by some reason it is not every time recognized, and it turns out that if I switch Off and On the power - it goes recognised , but I am trying no to switch the whole board, so I wonder if I use a transistor to make this switch - like BD139 will it cause some issue, or if there is a better solution ?
Here the circuit I am wondering about :
[image]

P.S. I have this board :
[image]

Comment: Before you get too far down this track you should try the PN532's powerdown/reset signal.

Comment: hey @timemage. Well.. How to do that ?

Comment: To know that the signal is even exposed on your board, we'd need to know which exact breakout you have, which might also inform other useful answers. You're asking about this circuit where you're try to control the PN532's GND which will have nothing to do with a prospective answer about RESET, again, assuming that's even possible. The NPN circuit itself is perhaps more ESE material. So, I'm not sure how you want to proceed. I'd give details on the breakout your using, code you're using, and how it's wired.

Comment: @timemage I jut added the board i have. I am using SPI. ( SCK / MISO / MOSI / SS ).

Comment: I've research on the net, and seems like this stall of the board is something common, which caused a lot of projects to fail.

Comment: There is a hardware Reset and Power-Down pin on pin38 of the chip, turn your board upside down and you will see a pin `RSTPDN` or something like that. Read about on-board LDO on page 85 and Hard Power-Down mode on page 91 of the [datasheet](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/nxp/data-sheets/PN532_C1.pdf) to get to know more.

Comment: Mine has a slightly different silkscreen, otherwise the same. I'd have liked to try their code and wiring scheme to replicate the problem to see that it actually solves it, but that hasn't materialized. Going to be away form the normal setup for a couple of days anyway now. If the code and wiring does show up, someone may answer with something completely different with the new information or be able to actually test your problem.

Comment: @YordanYanakiev, are you able to share your code?

Comment: I beieve this is the schematic for the PN532 Module shown in the photo https://www.elechouse.com/elechouse/images/product/PN532_module_V3/PN532_shematic_drowing.pdf

Comment: Looking now at the datasheet you've posted i realised that both SPI and I2C is marked 5V, while I am powering it from 3.3V ( as it is shown in most examples ) Could this cause the issue?

Comment: The manual for the (similar) module from Elechouse suggests it’s voltage tolerant. https://www.elechouse.com/elechouse/images/product/PN532_module_V3/PN532_%20Manual_V3.pdf

Comment: therefore this should not be an issue..

Comment: Hi @YordanYanakiev are you able to share your code and wiring setup? It would be interesting to see if the module recognition problem can be replicated. There may be a more elegant solution, but if power cycling using the RSTPD_N pin is the way forward suggestions can be made that fit with your code.

Comment: hey @RowanP sure. asap as i return from holydays will do.